# Can't read a file in python using node

Tags: python, node.js, express, spawn

I'm running python in a node web app, and I'm trying to load and read a file in python, do something with it, then spit it out to node.js.

When I run the following python code, nothing happens.

**Python**

```
import json
import sys

with open('trainingData.json') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

print(data)
print('hello from python')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

When I remove `with open`, then it works well. How can I read a file in python and call that file in node.js? Here's the node code

**Node**

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    const process = spawn('python', ['./python/script.py', 'Hello', 'World']);
    process.stdout.on('data', data => console.log(data.toString()));

    res.send('he');
});
```

(When I run the python file fro the terminal, it works correctly.)

Comment: Are your files in different directories? I'd try fully qualifying the location of the training data, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: It should work well, I believe your problem is in the path to `trainingData.json`. U might be writing it in `absolute` path when u remove `with`, ergo it works. But on your above-posted case, u most probably have a problem with assuming the path in which python runs.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The python file and the trainingData files are in the same directory, hence it does work when I run the python file in terminal

Comment: But is the *JS file* in the same directory? What's the working directory when the Python script is called by spawn? Again, if you try using a fully qualified location, does that work?

Comment: @jonrsharpe There we go. That worked. I had to put it in the same file as index.js, not where the spawn file is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Why does that happen?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Also, is there a way I can read errors? How did you figure this one out?

Comment: It happens because using spawn doesn't change the working directory to where the thing it's spawning is, unless you explicit set it via the cwd value in options: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options. I figured it out by guessing based on experience! If it worked when you ran it from the same directory, a different cwd seemed an obvious thing to test. You could have added try and except with some explicit printing to see the error message.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you! Can you make this into an answer so that I can accept it? (New to python. Thanks for your patience!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use spawn's cwd (current working directory) option, to specify the directory. To set it to the "current" current working directory use __dirname.

```
const process = spawn('python', ['./python/script.py', 'Hello', 'World'], {cwd: __dirname});
```